# How to convert array of string to date in pyspark?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is the dataframe schema structure.

```
root
 |-- validFrom: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

This is the pyspark query where I try to get the date datatype for `validFrom`.

```
df_02 = spark.sql("""
 select to_date(validFrom, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as  validFrom
 from   v_source_df_flatten
""");
```

But I receive the following error.

> due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires (string or date or
> timestamp) type, however, 'v_starhist_df_flatten.`validFrom`' is of
> array type.

What do I have to change in the `to_date` function?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to apply `to_date` on each element of the array using [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform).

```py
query = """
SELECT transform(validFrom, x -> to_date(x, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) as validFrom
FROM v_source_df_flatten
"""

df_02 = spark.sql(query)

df_02.printSchema()

"""
root
 |-- validFrom: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: date (containsNull = true)
"""

df_02.show(truncate=False)

"""
+------------------------+
|validFrom               |
+------------------------+
|[2021-10-10, 2022-10-10]|
|[2021-01-01, 2022-01-01]|
+------------------------+
"""
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert an array of string directly into `DateType`. `to_date` function expects a string date.

If you have only one date per array, then you can access simply the first element of the array and convert it to date like this:

```
spark.createDataFrame(
    [(["2022-01-01"],), (["2022-01-02"],)], ["validFrom"]
).createOrReplaceTempView("v_source_df_flatten")

df_02 = spark.sql("select to_date(validFrom[0]) as validFrom from v_source_df_flatten")

df_02.printSchema()
#root
# |-- validFrom: date (nullable = true)

df_02.show()
#+----------+
#| validFrom|
#+----------+
#|2022-01-01|
#|2022-01-02|
#+----------+
```

Notice that you can also use a simple cast as your dates have the default pattern `yyyy-MM-dd`:

```sql
cast(validFrom[0] as date) as validFrom
```

However, if your intent is to convert an array of strings into an array of dates, then you can use a cast in this particular case:

```
df_02 = spark.sql("select cast(validFrom as array<date>) as validFrom from v_source_df_flatten")

df_02.printSchema()
#root
# |-- validFrom: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: date (containsNull = true)

df_02.show()
#+------------+
#|   validFrom|
#+------------+
#|[2022-01-01]|
#|[2022-01-02]|
#+------------+
```

For date pattern different from `yyyy-MM-dd` you'll have to use `transform` on the array and apply `to_date` for each element as shown in the other answer.